# TypeError: Failed to parse URL from undefined(vercel deployment)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

any idea on how to fix the following error stack on vercel deployment?
the project is running fine locally but gets an error on vercel deployment.

> TypeError: Failed to parse URL from undefined/categories
> at new _Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5057:19)
> at i (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:177224)
> ... 4 lines matching cause stack trace ...
> at async b (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/608.js:13:3832) {   [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
> at new URL (node:internal/url:637:13)
> at new _Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5055:25)
> at i (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:177224)
> at F (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:39671)
> at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:41820
> at async globalThis.fetch (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:36415)
> at async f (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/608.js:13:3674)
> at async b (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/608.js:13:3832) {
> input: 'undefined/categories',
> code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'   }¡

repository: https://github.com/volfcan/ecommerce-store

Comment: if that's a Nextjs project, try : npm run build, it helps by showing what could be the error on a production version of your app. hope that helps